# Is there a way to run SQLite queries from python asynchronously or in parrallel?

Tags: python, sqlite, asynchronous, multicore

How can sqlite3 statements be run from python in some kind of "non-sequential" way?

Here is some code, basically straight from the python docs, on sqlite3.  (I am assuming this code is executing sequentially):

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('::memory')
c = conn.cursor()

###First sequence
c.execute('''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS stocks''')
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE stocks
             (date text, trans text, symbol text, qty real, price real)''')
c.execute("INSERT INTO stocks VALUES ('2006-01-05','BUY','SOME_STOCK',100,35.14)")
conn.commit()

result_stocks = c.execute('''SELECT * FROM stocks''').fetchall()

### Second Sequence
c.execute('''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bonds''')
# Create first table table
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE bonds
             (date text, trans text, symbol text, qty real, price real)''')
c.execute("INSERT INTO bonds VALUES ('2006-01-05','BUY','SOME_BOND',100,35.14)")
conn.commit()

result_bonds = c.execute('''SELECT * FROM bonds''').fetchall()

conn.close()

print(result_stocks)
print(result_bonds)
```

Is there a way to execute the "Second Sequence" without waiting for the "First Sequence" to finish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.**

SQLite databases may only be written to by one connection at a time; a write transaction will lock the entire database and prevent other threads and processes from reading or writing.

So yes, you can create a thread for each sequence, but since only one sequence can write to the database at any time, they don't execute concurrently, which defeats the purpose of running them asynchronously.

If however you are doing something else other than querying the database while your thread is running a query, then you will see a benefit, as the query thread will wait for the disk, freeing up the CPU to do other stuff. But in your example, there is no benefit to running the two sequences in separate threads.

Answer (score 1):

If you switch to `isolation_level=None`, you will be able to read from the database with much less friction than with the default mode.

I recommend you read this article for more tips on how to improve the performance:
http://charlesleifer.com/blog/going-fast-with-sqlite-and-python/?utm_content=bufferee5e3&utm_medium=social&utm_source=facebook.com&utm_campaign=buffer

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

However, you will need to run them in separate threads as the native sqlite3 module does not support async queries.

Comment: python sqlite3 lib is not thread-safe (at least in 2.7). Processes might work, but they come with their own overhead. There is the `check_same_thread=False` param, but in my experience, that had led to unpredictable behavior and python core-dumping.

Comment: @verboze You should not share connections in multiple threads (you can probably with your own locking), but you can create one connection for each thread and things should work.